# MongoDB, how to keep most recent data on one server and move older to another shard?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to keep new data on one server, and move older to next shard.

The first server would be highly available, because the user asks only for new data, older data is only for historical reasons.

Is it possible to choose a right shard-key or turn some options so shards will behave like tube, where data is transferred from one node to another with taking into account time when the document was added?

I've found a link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/DndTLcifsnQ but till this day it is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use the a flag as a component of the shard key and using the 2.2 Tag aware Sharding Feature. But, the downside is: you have to use this flag as the first key of the key list and use that key query for direct routing reasons.

There is a nice Blog Post out there, how to use these Tag aware Sharding. [Controlling Collection Distribution](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/07/25/controlling-collection-distribution/)

An alternative would be using two collections: one sharded (archive), one unsharded (active data).

Comment: Thanks for response! So lets consider that I have two shards tagged(oldData, newData) and data from 2010 to 2011 on those and I will call: sh.addTagRange('e','TimeStamp':'MinKey','TimeStamp':2010,'oldData') and sh.addTagRange('e','TimeStamp':'2011','TimeStamp':'MaxKey',newData') than after 2012 will finish I will need to call sh.addTagRange('e','TimeStamp':'MinKey', 'TimeStamp':2011,'oldData') and sh.addTagRange('e','TimeStamp':'2012','TimeStamp':'MaxKey',newData') manually or is it possible to put some Regexp or new Date() - 1year so tags will be calculated automatically?

Comment: you don't need a flag in the shard key - you can shard by date, the problem is that if you do any updates you need to know the shard key to do a targeted update.